# didInsertElement firing twice

Tags: ember.js

For some reason my view is firing didInsertElement twice.  There's nothing special about my code which is below.  I'm calling the view with the {{view}} helper within a template which is rendered using {{render "templateName"}} within another template which is displayed using the outlet of application.

```
App.PlaybackView = Ember.View.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        Ember.$(document).on('keyup', { _self: this }, this.handler);
    },
    handler: function(e) {
        if(e.which == 37) e.data._self.prev();
        if(e.which == 39) e.data._self.next();
    },
    prev: function() {
        this.get('controller').send('prev');
    },
    next: function(controller) {
        this.get('controller').send('next');
    }
});
```

Additionally, if I use the {{partial}} helper to display the parent template, then it is only fired once.  However, I don't have access to the controller I want by doing it that way.

Comment: I'm not seeing it, can you see what I have different? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ayinaxat/1/edit

Comment: Additionally we can use scheduleOnce to get around the issue, but we should find the underlying issue

Comment: that's essentially what I have... what other information can I give you that would be helpful?

Comment: Versions, the templates, or reproduce it in that jsbin.

Comment: Did you get it fixed?

Comment: hey @Johnny I don't believe I did...  you having troubles with something similar?

Comment: Ember can be so difficult to implement and understand. I get it fixed with a little hack. Thank you for your will of help.